# collapsing columns values in a specific order and leaving the missing values as NA in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am using R.

I have 4 different databases. Each one have values for my variables. Some of the bases have more values than others. So I want to use first the one that has the most values and lastly the one that have the least values. The data looks like this...

```
Variables   A   B   C   D

John        2   4   
Mike            6
Walter          7
Jennifer        9   8
Amanda      3
Carlos      9
Michael         3
James                   5
Kevin       4
Dennis              7
Frank
Steven
Joseph
Elvis           2
Maria           1
```

So, in roder to fill the data a need to create a new column that first uses the data of column B because is the one that contains the most values, then A, then C and then D and the ones that are missing need to be NA's. Also I need to add another column that gives me the reference of the data. In other words if I am using the column B to the that of John I need a column that tells me that the data pertains to column B.

The column should look like this...

```
Variables   E   D

John        4   B
Mike        6   B
Walter      7   B
Jennifer    9   B
Amanda      3   A
Carlos      9   A
Michael     3   B
James       5   D
Kevin       4   A
Dennis      7   C
Frank       NA  NA
Steven      NA  NA
Joseph      NA  NA
Elvis       2   B
Maria       1   B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can do the following...

Use `pivot_longer` to put into long form. Make `name` an `ordered` factor by "B", "A", "C", and "D". Then when you `arrange`, you can get the first value by this order within each person's name.

This assumes your missing data are `NA`. If they are instead blank character values, you can `filter` those out with `filter(value != "")` instead of `drop_na(value)`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Variables) %>%
  mutate(name = ordered(name, levels = c('B', 'A', 'C', 'D'))) %>%
  group_by(Variables) %>%
  drop_na(value) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  summarise(E = first(value),
            New_D = first(name)) %>%
  right_join(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Variables     E New_D     A     B     C     D
   <chr>     <dbl> <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Amanda        3 A         3    NA    NA    NA
 2 Carlos        9 A         9    NA    NA    NA
 3 Dennis        7 C        NA    NA     7    NA
 4 Elvis         2 B        NA     2    NA    NA
 5 James         5 D        NA    NA    NA     5
 6 Jennifer      9 B        NA     9     8    NA
 7 John          4 B         2     4    NA    NA
 8 Kevin         4 A         4    NA    NA    NA
 9 Maria         1 B        NA     1    NA    NA
10 Michael       3 B        NA     3    NA    NA
11 Mike          6 B        NA     6    NA    NA
12 Walter        7 B        NA     7    NA    NA
13 Frank        NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA
14 Steven       NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA
15 Joseph       NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Variables = c("John", "Mike", "Walter", "Jennifer", 
"Amanda", "Carlos", "Michael", "James", "Kevin", "Dennis", "Frank", 
"Steven", "Joseph", "Elvis", "Maria"), A = c(2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
9, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(4, 6, 7, 9, NA, 
NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), D = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```